# Url issue for ViewSet retrieve when pk includes a '.'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a ViewSet that looks like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
```

And I'm using the built in urls with:

```
router.register(r'clients', ClientsViewSet)
```

I am having an issue where I am getting a 404 if my primary key includes a '.' character. I don't think that the '.' needs to be escaped. If I remove the '.' from the pk in my database, the lookup works fine.

The failing url is: http://localhost:8000/clients/Bill.Murray

This one works: http://localhost:8000/clients/BillMurray

What would be the cause of this not working? Is there a way around it so that I can do a retrieve with the PK and still have the '.' included?

Comment: You can't have a `.` character in the path section of a URL. You could try escaping it `http://localhost:8000/clients/Bill%2EMurray`, if that does not work you will have to use a path that does not contain a `.`

Comment: Thanks for the info.